# WSUS update not showing up

Tags: wsus

We're having issues with WSUS.

We have an update, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2790947, which we imported in WSUS (it's not in the standard collection), it's an import from the MS website.

The Update is set to install on all servers. However on servers with SQL Server 2012 SP1 we don't see the update in the Windows Update window.

The question is: is there anything extra I have to do to get this manual update pushed through? I've checked the install, and it's set to all computers (Install, Inherited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also worthy of note that the update will not appear in the WUApp for installation until

- The update is approved for an appropriate target group on the WSUS Server.
- The update installation file is downloaded from Microsoft to the WSUS server.
- The client system has executed a detection and found the approved/available update.
- The client system has downloaded the update and made it available to the end-user for installation.

Comment: It seeems that the detection mechanism isn't working. The WSUS admin says that all computers either have the update or it's not applicable, even though I've checked, and it's not installed.

Answer (score 0):

***Make sure that the update is actually needed***

> "One cumulative hotfix package includes all the component packages. The cumulative update package updates only those components that are installed on the system. Source: your link"

***Force client resync to WSUS ***

> wuauclt /detectnow